# Amazon Mechanical Turk - ExternalHit Sample

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I'm tyring to run the ExternalHit Sample that comes with the Command Line Tools installer. For the .question file I have the following ...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ExternalQuestionxmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2006-07-14/ExternalQuestion.xsd">
<ExternalURL>https://s3.amazonaws.com/MTurk_test/externalpage.htm?url=${helper.urlencode($urls)}</ExternalURL>
<FrameHeight>450</FrameHeight>
```

We kept the input file the same as in the sample. When we loadhits in either the sandbox or the standard mechanical turk interface the input variable (i.e. the web page) does not display in the frame. Additionally, you can select a radio button but you cannot submit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're running into two problems here:

1. Due to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), the `<iframe>` in the resulting page is not going to display an arbitrary URL.
2. Even if it could display an arbitrary URL, that URL would have to be configured for SSL.

So, you'll be able to load this (another amazon URL using SSL):

https://s3.amazonaws.com/MTurk_test/externalpage.htm?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mturk.com

But not this (amazon URL w/o SSL):

https://s3.amazonaws.com/MTurk_test/externalpage.htm?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mturk.com

And not an arbitrary URL (even with SSL):

https://s3.amazonaws.com/MTurk_test/externalpage.htm?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com

So, my guess is that this template is horribly outdated and used to work at some point in the past but is not compliant with modern web browser technology.

Best solution is just to provide a link for the worker to click to visit the URL.

Comment: It's worth noting that this will work for some sites, but not others (even despite #1). That's because the restrictions on #1 are configurable by the site operator, and some are more lax than others about what content can appear in an IFRAME. Here's an example that "just works" out of the box, and it's not an amazon URL (believe it or not, mturk.com and amazonaws.om aren't really 'same origin' in the strict sense): https://s3.amazonaws.com/MTurk_test/externalpage.htm?url=https://www.bing.com/